# When using assignment operator overloading, the new object isn't accessible outside of operator=()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have an implementation of a Queue which requires writing an assignment operator overload.

```
Queue& Queue::operator= (const Queue& rhs){
  if(this->head == rhs.head) return *this;

  Queue * newlist;
  if(rhs.head == NULL){ 
    // copying over an empty list will clear it.
    this->clear();
    return * newlist;
  }

  newlist = new Queue(rhs);
  cout << "made new queue" << endl;

  cout << "new list : " << * newlist << endl;
  return * newlist;
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I leave this function, the contents of `newlist` are no longer accessible. How is an operator=() function supposed to look?

EDIT:
queue.h:

```
class Queue : public LinkedList {
protected:
    unsigned maxSize;

public:
    Queue(unsigned N = -1);
    Queue(const Collection& collection, unsigned N = -1);
    ~Queue();
    Queue(const Queue& obj);
    Queue& operator= (const Queue& rhs);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostream, const Queue &rhs);
    bool add(myType element);
    myType element();
    bool offer(myType element);
    myType peek();
    myType poll();
    myType remove();

};
```

Comment: It's hard to say what it should look like without seeing you `Queue` class.  Jefffrey pretty much nailed the answer though.

Comment: You are using new/delete totally wrong - avoid it until you know how to pair new/delete or delegate the delete to a smart pointer.

Comment: `return * newlist;` is undefined behavior when `rhs.head == NULL`, since at that point, `newlist` is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: I have included queue.h but it might not be useful without linkedlist.h .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is an `operator=()` function supposed to look?

An `operator=` is supposed to modify the internal object `(*this)` with the values of `rhs` and then literally return `(*this)`.